# Laravel mail provide sender detail

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-mail

I need to get my user email address along with form data in order to set `->from()` in my mailable file

## code

`controller function`

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'product' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'message' => 'required|string',
        ]);

        $user = $request->user(); // need to add this

        $inquery = new Inquery;
        $inquery->user_id = $user->id;
        $inquery->product = $request->input('product');
        $inquery->email = $request->input('email');
        $inquery->message = $request->input('message');
        $inquery->save();

        Mail::to('xyz@example.com')->send(new InquiryToAdmin($inquery));
}
```

`Mailable file`

```
class InquiryToAdmin extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $data;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from($user['email'])->subject('New Inquiry was sent')->view('emails.inquiry.admin');
    }
}
```

> NOTE:
>
> What I need is to get `->from($user['email'])` for that i need to send my `$user` from controller to mailable file (commented in code), the problem is I cannot set `$user` to be send to my mailable file.

Any idea?

Comment: are you getting `$user` in controller check `dd($user)` you want know how to pass to mailable class ?

Comment: @Hamelraj yes i get user info also i can save that `$inquery->user_id` value, so the user in controller is good.

Comment: `$inquary` is passed to your mailable, if you want to pass `$user` then you need to pass it as second argument in `InquiryToAdmin($inquiry, $user)` and then you can set both in constructor.

Comment: @Hamelraj yes i need to pass both `$data` and `$user` to mailable class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Mail::to('xyz@example.com')->send(new InquiryToAdmin($inquery,$user));

class InquiryToAdmin extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $data;
    protected $user;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data,$user)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from($this->user->email)->subject('New Inquiry was sent')->view('emails.inquiry.admin');
    }
}
```

Comment: it says `Undefined variable: user`

Comment: change `protected $user;`  **protected ** and check

Comment: are you passing user here `new InquiryToAdmin($inquery,$user)` ??

Comment: can you tell which file you get this error  `InquiryToAdmin` or in your controller ?

Comment: change `protected $user;` to `private $user;`

Comment: hold on! i wasn't add `$user` to `__construt` now i get `Undefined variable: data`

Comment: ok it fixed after i add `$user` to `__construt` and changed variables to `public $data` it works.  Thank you

Comment: keep data as public and check